Add Shortcode functionality to a function that queries custom post type / taxonomy
How to output a UL of items and URLS for custom taxonomy?
The plugin 'CPT UI' (Custom Post Type UI) is very good at creating custom post types.
I have created a post type called 'Towns' that has a range of local towns assigned to it. (Also have 'Regions' and 'Experiences'.)
I wish to create a shortcode that queries the custom post type and displays an unordered list to a page with the ability to add classes (like Shortcodes Ultimate).
This is the code the that CPT UI has generated to register a taxonomy in the functions.php file. How can this be modified to enable a shortcode to be used to display a list e.g. [cptui tax="town" class="town-list"]?

    /**
     * Taxonomy: Towns.
     */

    $labels = [
        "name" => esc_html__( "Towns", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "singular_name" => esc_html__( "Town", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
    ];

    
    $args = [
        "label" => esc_html__( "Towns", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "query_var" => true,
        "rewrite" => [ 'slug' => 'town', 'with_front' => true, ],
        "show_admin_column" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "show_tagcloud" => false,
        "rest_base" => "town",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Terms_Controller",
        "rest_namespace" => "wp/v2",
        "show_in_quick_edit" => false,
        "sort" => false,
        "show_in_graphql" => false,
    ];
    register_taxonomy( "town", [ "wpsl_stores" ], $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_town' );```

